# Select different values from multiple tables mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have problem to retrieve different values from some tables in mysql.
here's my query:

```
select profile_term.*,application_gmbr.gmb,application.name_app from
relasi_useraplikasi,
(profile_term inner join application_gmbr on
profile_term.id_app=application_gmbr.id_app) inner join application ON
profile_term.id_app=application.id_app
where relasi_useraplikasi.id_user='2' 
and application_gmbr.id_app not like relasi_useraplikasi.id_app 
and profile_term.id_app not like relasi_useraplikasi.id_app
and application.id_app not like relasi_useraplikasi.id_app 
GROUP BY application.id_app
order by score asc limit 5;
```

This doesn't work I still get values where id_app in relasi_useraplikasi.id_app.

I want to get data from profile_term,application_gmbr,application where profile_term.id_app,application_gmbr.id_app,application.id_app different with relasi_useraplikasi.id_app.

this is my data table:

1.profile_term

```
id_app||profile
================
  1        A
  2        B
  3        C
  4        D
  5        E
```

2.application_gmbr

```
 id_app||gmb
===============
   1      p1
   2      p2
   3      p3
   4      p4
   5      p5
```

3.application

```
 id_app||name_app
===============
   1      app1
   2      app2
   3      app3
   4      app4
   5      app5
```

3.relasi_useraplikasi

```
 id_app||id_user
===============
   1      1
   2      2
   3      3
   4      4
   5      5
```

result that I want, gives me all record that I want without id_app where id_user=2 in relasi_useraplikasi:

```
   id_app||profile|| gmb ||name_app
   ==================================
    1        A       p1      app1
    3        C       p3      app3
    4        D       p4      app4
    5        E       p5      app5
```

Any helps would be appreciated

Comment: Please add some sample data and an exemple of the result you want

Comment: How does relasi_useraplikasi relate to profile_term?

Comment: I just edited my question and they all have id_app what I want is get all record without id_app that id_user=2 has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This doesn't work I still get values where id_app in relasi_useraplikasi.id_app."

If you want the condition to be that no rows are displayed that have one of the '
relasi_useraplikasi.id_app' you can use 'not  in' with a subquery.

For example: 'application_gmbr.id_app not in (select distinct  relasi_useraplikasi.id_app from relasi_useraplikasi)'

Comment: it gives me error

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'relasi_useraplikasi.id_app 
and profile_term.id_app not in relasi_useraplikasi.' at line 5

Comment: well,thanks it works..
using not in and select distinct.


thanks for your help, @meeWok

Comment: This answer will perform terribly, as the subquery will be executed for each result in the outer query.  The "proper" way to do this is with a JOIN.

Comment: @feroAditya have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87063/5 ... is the second query result more what you want?

Comment: yes thanks..
that's good answer..
really helps me alot..
thanks for all of u,guys